# remove middle mouse axis lock ?

Tags: shortcut

i find it very annoying that you cant move and rotate the view while doing a rotation/scale/translation

i just want to uncheck the "axis lock = middle mouse button" option but i cant find that in the input propreties ... can someone help me ?

thanks a lot !
im kind of struggling here

i already tried to find it but i think theres no option at all inside of this shortcut pref menu ...

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this is configurable, grab/rotate/scale and similar operations are so called "modal operators", which define a new input "mode"/button scheme which is not exposed to the user preferences.